# Websocket gives error 500 once deployed but works on dev

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to deploy a django app using django-channels. When I run the server in a dev environment, it works perfectly. But when deployed, the websocket crash with an error 500.

I use django 2.2.2, channels 2.2.0 and asgiref 3.1.4, on a linux debian stretch 9.9 VPS, with python 3.6 (compiled myself because not available on stretch) and nginx engine.

I followed for deployment tutorials on https://djangodeployment.readthedocs.io/en/latest/01-getting-started.html and for the channels i tried to adapt the page https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html but mostly https://avilpage.com/2018/05/deploying-scaling-django-channels.html

I'm quite noob to redis and all these things, at first I had redis working on port 6379, but it was with the main user of the system I used to do some tests in a dev environment, not the user for the django app. So I did another command to run docker on port 6479 for the django app user, which seemed to work. Then I had 404 error but it was because of nginx not configured properly for websocket. Now, I have the 500 error.

here is the traceback of django when I try to open the websocket:

```
[2019-08-19 12:54:46,857] ERROR: Exception inside application: Connection has been closed by server
  File "/opt/knightools/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 183, in __call__
    return await self.inner(receive, self.send)
  File "/opt/knightools/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 41, in coroutine_call
    await inner_instance(receive, send)
  File "/opt/knightools/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 59, in __call__
    [receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch
  File "/opt/knightools/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 59, in await_many_dispatch
    await task
  File "/opt/knightools/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 429, in receive
    real_channel
  File "/opt/knightools/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 484, in receive_single
    index, channel_key, timeout=self.brpop_timeout
  File "/opt/knightools/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py", line 327, in _brpop_with_clean
    await connection.eval(cleanup_script, keys=[], args=[channel, backup_queue])
  Connection has been closed by server
```

From what I've seen on the net, it could be a redis configuration/installation issue, but why then does it works correctly when runned with `manage.py runserver`? What is the proper way to run the docker? I see the trace starts at session, so maybe I have a problem with them, but they are correctly stored inside the database (as far as I can see).

I'm totally lost, so thank you if you can help me.

Comment: You changed the redis port to 6479 (first it was 6379) according to what you write? Did you also change the corresponding settings?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Yes I changed them, and recompiled the settings.py accordingly to the manual of djangodeployment. To be sure, I must admit I tried all port I setup (6379 for main user, 6479 for django-app user, 6579 for root user just to be sure), each time recompiling to be sure it's not from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after more tests, I noticed even the `manage.py runserver` wasn't working anymore. Now it works, so that's what I did, in case someone else come to this trouble:

I wiped out every docker by using the command:

```
docker ps
```

on the last column there is the name. Then, for each name, do:

```
docker stop <name>
docker rm <name>
```

Once done, I just launched the default redis server with 6379 port with the django-app user:

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:2.8
```

Update settings accordingly, recompile settings if you have to, reload your services about the django-app, then it should work (at least it worked for me).

As I said, don't know anything about redis or docker, so maybe there was conflict.

Hope it will help.